# Does Force of Personality stack with Rallying Presence?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, warlord

Do the [Warlord](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/path-of-war/classes/warlord/#TOC-Tactical-Presence-Ex-) class abilities that provide their Charisma bonus to saves stack? I believe (though I can't find the link) that in the past double stacking of abilities has been disallowed.

Rallying Presence

> Rallying Presence: The sight of a warlord on the battlefield is enough
>   to strengthen the hearts and wills of those who fight beside him in
>   battle. At 5th level, the warlord may add his warlord initiation
>   modifier as a morale bonus to Will saves versus fear, death effect, or
>   compulsion effects to all allies within 30-ft. of his position. If the
>   warlord maintaining this presence becomes cowed, frightened, panicked
>   or falls prey to a hostile mind-affecting ability (such as one that
>   would stun or daze him), compulsion or death effect, this presence
>   immediately ends.

Force of Personality (Ex)

> At 3rd level, the warlord’s forceful personality and bold, headstrong
>   nature assist him in resisting the influence of others. Where others
>   use personal serenity, awareness of the world around them, or plain
>   old sensibility, the warlord gets by with endless nerve. The warlord
>   may add his warlord initiation modifier in addition to his Wisdom
>   modifier to determine his Will save bonus. If the character is ever
>   able to add his warlord initiation modifier to his Will save through
>   use of another ability (for example. the paladin’s divine grace) he
>   may only add his warlord initiation modifier once to his Will save.

Answer (score 2):

Force of Personality answers the question for you in the last sentence.

> If the character is ever able to add his warlord initiation modifier
>   to his Will save through use of another ability (for example. the
>   paladin’s divine grace) he may only add his warlord initiation
>   modifier once to his Will save.

You get initiation bonus once.

Comment: Edited for the objection, though I would have to laugh at Paizo for that one; it takes two or more to make an alliance (thus being allies), so does this mean all PCs have Dissociative identity disorder by proxy?